# Is there a build in "slow" Future.traverse version?

Tags: scala, future

I discovered that building a lot of Futures for one user request generally is a bad practice. These Futures can fill an execution context which will affect other requests. This is unlikely something you really want. Keeping Futures number small is quite simple - create new Futures only in for-comprehensions, using flatMap, etc. But sometimes it could be necessary to to create a Future for each Seq item. Using Future.sequence or Future.traverse cause problem described above. So I ended up with this solution, which doesn't create Futures for each collection item simultaneously:

```
  def ftraverse[A, B](xs: Seq[A])(f: A => Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[B]] = {
    if(xs.isEmpty) Future successful Seq.empty[B]
    else f(xs.head) flatMap { fh => ftraverse(xs.tail)(f) map (r => fh +: r) }
  }
```

I wonder, maybe I'm inventing a wheel and actually such function already exists somewhere in Scala's standart library? Also I would like to know, did you encountered described problem and how did you solve it? Maybe, if this is a well known issue with Futures, I should create a pull request in Future.scala so this function (or more generalized version of it) would be included in standard library?

UPD: More general version, whith limited parallelism:

```
  def ftraverse[A, B](xs: Seq[A], chunkSize: Int, maxChunks: Int)(f: A => Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[B]] = {
    val xss = xs.grouped(chunkSize).toList
    val chunks = xss.take(maxChunks-1) :+ xss.drop(maxChunks-1).flatten
    Future.sequence{ chunks.map(chunk => ftraverse(chunk)(f) ) } map { _.flatten }
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at 'Task' in scalaz. It implements `traverse` as defined in the Haskell Traversable typeclass, which behaves this way (One operation at a time).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there isn't anything like this in the standard library. Whether there *should* be or not, I can't say. I don't think it's very common to want to execute `Future`s in a strict sequence. But when you want to, it's very easy to implement your own method to do so, as you have. I personally just keep a method in my own libraries for this purpose. It would however be convenient to have a way to do this with the standard library, though. If there *were*, it should be more generic.

It is actually very simple to modify the current `traverse` to process `Future`s sequentially, instead of in parallel. Here is the [current version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L572-576), which uses `foldLeft` instead of recursion:

```
def traverse[A, B, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[B]] =
    in.foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) =>
      val fb = fn(a)
      for (r <- fr; b <- fb) yield (r += b)
    }.map(_.result())
```

The `Future`s are created before the `flatMap` by assigning `val fb = fn(a)` (and thus executed before). All one needs to do is move `fn(a)` inside the `flatMap` to delay the creation of subsequent `Future`s in the collection.

```
def traverseSeq[A, B, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[B]] =
    in.foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) =>
      for (r <- fr; b <- fn(a)) yield (r += b)
    }.map(_.result())
```

Another way you can limit the impact of executing a large number of `Future`s is by using a different `ExecutionContext` for them. For example in a web app, I might keep one `ExecutionContext` for database calls, one for calls to Amazon S3, and one for slow database calls.

A very simple implementation could use fixed thread pools:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)
```

A large number of `Future`s executing here would fill the `ExecutionContext`, but it would prevent them from filling other contexts.

If you're using Akka, you can easily create `ExecutionContext`s from configuration using [Dispatchers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html) within an `ActorSystem`:

```
my-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "fork-join-executor"
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 2
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
  throughput = 100
}
```

If you have an `ActorSystem` called `system` you could then access it via:

```
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("my-dispatcher")
```

All of this depends on your use case. While I do separate my asynchronous computations into different contexts, there are times when I still want to `traverse` sequentially to smooth out the usage of these contexts.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your problem is not related to the number of futures you create, but the fairness with which they're executed. Consider how callbacks on futures (`map`, `flatMap`, `onComplete`, `fold`, etc) are processed: they are placed in an executor's queue and are executed when the results of their parent futures are completed.

If all of your futures share the same executor (i.e., queue), they will indeed clobber each other as you say. A common way to solve this fairness issue is to use Akka actors. For each request, spin up a new actor (with its own queue) and have all actors *of that type* share an `ExecutionContext`. You can limit the maximum number of messages an actor will execute before moving on to another actor sharing that `ExecutionContext` using the `throughput` configuration property.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what the parallel collections are for?

```
val parArray = (1 to 1000000).toArray.par
sum = parArray.map(_ + _)
res0: Int = 1784293664
```

looks like a normal synchronous method call, but the parallel collection will use a threadpool to calculate the map in parallel (race conditions!). You will find more details here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried to clean up my answer and put the most important informations in there

Comment: Please note, that the question was not about how to do things in parallel, but an opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the create of futures isn't so finely grained that the overhead will be prohibitive (in which case the answer suggesting use of the parallel collections is probably the most useful), you could just create a different, implicitly defined execution context for the futures to run under that is backed by a different executor with it's own threads.

You can call `ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService` or `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor` to do so.